# What is this strange thing?

Tags: identification, soil

While freshening some soil for fall planting (garlic), I found several of these weird yellow globules:

[image]

Each one is maybe 3mm in diameter and resembles a fish egg, both in appearance and in consistency (i.e., they burst under pressure and are filled with some sort of liquid). My guess is that they're eggs of some kind, but only because of the resemblance to fish eggs. What are they?

Comment: Egg yes, slug or snail probably. Not sure.

Comment: Small lizard egg; although those I encounter are white and are more "egg" shaped. Maybe fertilizer like osmocote  , I have never squashed one so don't know what is inside.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - I was thinking Osmocote, too, but they're solid and turn to powder when crushed. Interesting question.